# Android alternative for google maps (offline)

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I'm working on an app where users could press a button to see a map. I've implemented that google maps opens inside the app to show a map.

Now my question is: If there is no wifi/3G it is impossible to cache the map, is there another way to show an offline version of the map?

I was thinking about showing an svg image of a map. I've tried that but there is no way to zoom in the svg image, so is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Open Street Map instead of Google Maps.
There is an Android library which works great online and offline: [OSMDroid](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/)

Answer (score 0):

The old version of maps/navigation had a declared place in maps where you could save a map to the device for offline viewing. Since they did their push to combine the two into a single app in June/July or so... the only way you can do this now is to zoom to the map area you want, and search for "okay maps" (this is a really hacky way to do it) and it will save an offline version of the map to the device.

Personally, I think Google has really dropped the ball on this one, and shouldn't have combined the two applications until AFTER the resulting application was better (all the same old features and possibly more new ones) than the previous old ones.

You might want to look at the Google maps API (which I have not yet done) and see if there is a way to request a cache be stored of an area. (or if this is a future goal).

As for drop in replacement... I'm not aware of one.