# is getting mapview working without api key possible on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-mapview

I am creating app to only show information about me, I wanna show the location on the map, then user can go from the mapview to the google maps to navigate if he wanted.

So, I dont wanna navigate, i dont wanna use maps api, i dont wanna use api key.
I just want to show a mapview then user can switch from the mapview to google maps.

**is that possible ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

API_KEY is the way of Google to track number of Users using Map API and also promote new features and updates. I don't find any reason why you don't want to use API_KEY.

Follow this [tutorial](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/obtaining_a_google_maps_api_key/) which has Graphic content to use API_KEY to generate Maps.

Comment: because some developers (as for me) don't have google account and I don't want to have one either, one of the best alternative is OSMDroid, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233414/android-alternative-for-google-maps-offline

Answer (score 4):

> I wanna show the location on the map

To do this, you need to interact with the map.
To be able to interact with the map you need an API key.

So no, that's not possible.